# How do I add a program with a directory of dependencies to $PATH?

Tags: software-installation, path, executable, libraries

I want to add a program to my `$PATH`, but its code is split into various files that it imports at run-time from a `lib/` in its root directory.

```
projectRootDirectory
├ programBinary
└ lib
  ├ someLibrary
  └ someLibrary2
```

How do I add such a program to my `$PATH` without it complaining about missing dependencies?

---

I'd normally get the binary into `/usr/local/bin` by

- copying

  ```
  cp /path/to/programBinary /usr/local/bin
  ```
- or symlinking

  ```
  cd /usr/local/bin
  ln -s /path/to/programBinary programBinary
  ```

but both make it fail to find its dependencies.

I can't move the whole directory into `/usr/local/bin` because some of the required files are executables too, which I don't want cluttering my `$PATH`.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It's expecting particular libraries to be present in the same directory as the executable. (For this particular program, the message is : "`Unable to access jarfile: /usr/local/bin/savilerow.jar`" when symlinked in `/usr/local/bin`.)

Comment: This is what binary packages are for. I recommend learning how to make a binary package for your distribution, if you don't know how to do so already. You'll find most of these issues go away. The two major flavors are, of course, rpm and deb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course add `projectRootDirectory` to your `$PATH`, but this has at least two drawbacks:

- It looks like, the way you are describing it, this particular project does not organize its project nicely into `bin` and `lib` subdirectories like so:

  ```
  projectRootDirectory
  ├ bin
  │ └ programBinary
  └ lib
    ├ someLibrary
    └ someLibrary2
  ```

  therefore you'd be forced to put `projectRootDirectory` itself into the `$PATH`, and since that contains other things besides binaries intended for execution, it's a bit ugly.
- If you have many similar projects, the contents of your `$PATH` will proliferate out of control.

Instead, the simplest thing you can probably do in this particular case is to place a wrapper executable in `/usr/local/bin`, which is a very simple shell script that just runs the "real" program from the location where it lives.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec projectRootDirectory/programBinary "$@"
```

Since the wrapper script is calling it with its full pathname, it will probably be able to locate its auxiliary files in the manner it normally does.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of different complexity to approach that issue, and what fits best depends on your "packaging philosophy".

The approach I'd probably choose is to have a wrapper script in your `/usr/local/bin` directory that does nothing but setting the exported `PATH` variable, modified by your library path, and call the main program in your library path; in this case all executables would reside in your lib directory, only the initial wrapper script in `/usr/local/bin`. (The locally defined `PATH` variable will only be inherited by the called processes and not taint the calling environment.)